# How to find connected cells in a grid using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I am doing a problem that gives a grid such as:

1 1 0 0

0 1 1 0

0 0 1 0

1 0 0 0

n = number of rows and m = number of columns.

The problem is to find the most connected chain  of "1" in the grid...in this case: it is the 1-1-1-1-1 from cell (0,0) to cell (2,2).

Here is my code so far:

```
def find(x, y):
     #uses recursive fill
     if x < 0 or y < 0 or matrix[x][y] == -1 or matrix[x][y] == 0 or x>n or y>m:
         return 0
     else:
         return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y) + find(x, y+1) + find(x, y-1)+ find(x+1, y-1)+ find(x-1,y+1) + find(x+1, y+1) + find(x-1, y-1)

matrix = [[0 for a in range(n)] for b in range(m)]

#captures data and puts it in a matrix
for i in range(n):
    row = map(int, raw_input().strip().split())
    for j in range(m):
        matrix[i][j] = row[j]

sums = 0
for i in range(n):
    for k in range(m):
        if matrix[i][k] == 1:
            print matrix[i][k]
            sums = max(find(i, k))

print sums
```

Right now, I am getting a "Runtime Error" when I run this program but I can't figure out why. I am doing the recursive fill in the `find` function. The rest of the code just stores values from `raw_input()` into a matrix and enters the `find` function if the cell is equal to 1.

EDIT:

I am getting a long repeated error that looks like this (shortened):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 27, in <module>
    sums = max(find(i, k))
  File "solution.py", line 11, in find
    return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y) + find(x, y+1) + find(x, y-1)+ find(x+1, y-1)+ find(x-1,y+1) + find(x+1, y+1) + find(x-1, y-1)
  File "solution.py", line 11, in find
    return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y) + find(x, y+1) + find(x, y-1)+ find(x+1, y-1)+ find(x-1,y+1) + find(x+1, y+1) + find(x-1, y-1)
  File "solution.py", line 11, in find
    return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y) + find(x, y+1) + find(x, y-1)+ find(x+1, y-1)+ find(x-1,y+1) + find(x+1, y+1) + find(x-1, y-1)
  File "solution.py", line 11, in find
    return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y) + find(x, y+1) + find(x, y-1)+ find(x+1, y-1)+ find(x-1,y+1) + find(x+1, y+1) + find(x-1, y-1)
  File "solution.py", line 11, in find
    return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y) + find(x, y+1) + find(x, y-1)+ find(x+1, y-1)+ find(x-1,y+1) + find(x+1, y+1) + find(x-1, y-1)
  File "solution.py", line 11, in find
```

Also this solution is probably not the best (I'm new at Python), so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: I added the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `x>n or y>m` before `matrix[x][y] == -1 or matrix[x][y] == 0`. Otherwise it can lead to `out of range` error.

And also you should mark somehow your way or you will end up in infinite recursion. In your example you will go right->left->right->left... and always find `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into infinite recursion because

1. you start in the upper right corner
2. you find a `1`, so you `return 1 + find(x+1, y) + ...`
3. now you're looking at the next `1` right to the first one
4. so you `return 1 + find(x+1, y) + find(x-1, y)`
5. thereby looking at the `1` in the upper right corner again (`x-1, y`)
6. goto 1

Possible solution: mark "used" positions, maybe with `2`.

Comment: Yes, before the `return 1+...` part. You already check for `matrix [x][y]==-1`, why do you do this? You can also use -1 as marker.

Comment: Marking it with `2` will break other solutions.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to follow another recursive fill example online, but adding the marker makes sense now. Also, I changed the line `sums = max(find(i, k))` into `sums = max(sums, find(i, k))` and now I'm getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'`. I used a `try...except TypeError` and I think that solves it temporarily. But I don't think that's the best solution for that? If you have any ideas, I would love to hear it! Thanks!

Comment: Your `find` function now seems to finish without returning anything so you get `None`.